# Get customer orders in PrestaShop Web services

Tags: api, web-services, prestashop

I just installed the PrestaShop API and it seems there is no way to find how to retrieve customer orders. I have the customers list, I have the orders list but I have nothing to link them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`http://localhost/api/orders?filter[id_customer]=[1]`

there few other filters exists, [more in docs](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+Use)

Comment: That's it ! I must have seen this before but I did not make the link... Thanks :)

Comment: you saved my day buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Work with v1.7.x:

`$orders = Order::getCustomerOrders($id_customer);`

Answer (score 0):

If you also need get order details (like products), you can use this:

```
$order          =   new Order($id_order['id_order']);
$products       =   $order->getProducts();
```